# Mule 4 : How to implement a policy in Mule 4 app and exclude API?

Tags: mule4

Scenario: After creating and adding an API in API exchange, we can add a policy like a rate limiting to it. After the policy is created we have the API fragment that we copy and paste in our RAML API specification.

My question is can we define the policy in RAML and implement the policy logic directly in the Mule app and remove the API Proxy in between.
If yes, can someone also please share the link to examples if there are any?

Answer (score 0):

Add an autodiscovery element to your application. This is the Basic Endpoint use case described at https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/api-auto-discovery-new-concept#proxy-endpoint-vs-basic-endpoint and https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/configure-autodiscovery-4-task (assuming you are using Mule 4).

You need to configure everything manually, instead of the proxy which is autogenerated.

Comment: let me explain my concern with an example. For example, In API Exchange, after adding an API i can create a ANPI proxy and add the Basic Auth policy. This will give me a API fragment. Now we can copy this API fragment in our RAML as well . But what if I do not want to use the proxy? we can implement the basic auth in our Mule 4 app directly. Is something similar possible meaning can we have a rate limiting logic in Mule 4 app and exclude the API proxy?

Comment: If you implement the auto discovery in the application directly you can apply the policies directly to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in RAML as you described in your question.

but to add any policy logic other than the policies that are available in your API Manager, you can create your own custom policy and after creating upload that in your API manager and apply them.
Thanks